# node async function with nested function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently I am trying to have an async function which has another function inside like this:

```
processFile: async function(req, whatTo, callback){

    const lines = [];

    const lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: require('streamifier').createReadStream(req.file.buffer)
    });

    let errorPresent = false;

    lineReader.on('line', line => {
        lines.push(line.replace(/ /g,''));
    });

    lineReader.on('close', async () => {

        try {

            const results = await Promise.map(lines, async(line) => {

                return await Transform(line);

            }, { concurrency: 80 });

            return results.join("\r\n");

        }catch(err){
            throw err;
        }

    });

}
```

Then I have a route, which calls this function, like this:

```
const data = await tokenizer.processFile(req, 'tokenize');

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain'); 
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=tokenized.txt');
res.write(data, 'binary');
res.end();
```

The `return results.join("\r\n");` isn't 'returning' the processFile.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Callbacks and async/await oh my

Comment: Can you describe the exact behavior you are expecting?  There seem to be several issues with your code and I can't tell what path you are actually trying to go down.  For example, `processFile` doesn't actually return anything and doesn't really wait to return, the `async` is superfluous.  Also, the mixing of eventful and asynchronous code doesn't make sense either.  You're mixing callbacks, async/await, and explicit Promises in a way that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @CodyG. Well... how do you suggest I return results.join("\r\n") from within `lineReader.on('close', async () ...`? I did mention I'm new to Node?

Comment: @CodyG. I edited the question removing callbacks and only left the async/await. Now, how do I get to return results.join("\r\n")?

Comment: (Is this a big file?) I've given a really rough answer (it might not work as is) but if you have any questions let me know.

Comment: It is. And the `Transform()` actually calls an HTTP service that supports over 1000TPS, and therefore it parallelizing the requests could decrease processing a lot.

Comment: If you want an explanation for why your `return` doesn't work:  it's inside a callback function (which is a promise) and then nothing .then()'s that promise. linereader.on('close') doesn't return anything, so there's no way that you can return from your `async processFile()`. Moral of the story is don't try to convert callbacks directly to async/await, it's not possible.

Comment: If it's a large file you should not be pushing lines into an array, should you? Shouldn't you be streaming the results into something else?  If you need to parallelize readline .on('line') for your `Transform()` function that's a different issue...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172914/discussion-between-fede-e-and-cody-g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to split up your conversion of line reader from cb to a promise doing something like this:

```
processFile: (req, whatTo) => new Promise((res,rej)=>{

    const lines = [];

    const lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: require('streamifier').createReadStream(req.file.buffer)
    });

    let errorPresent = false;

    lineReader.on('line', line => {
        lines.push(line.replace(/ /g,''));
    });

    lineReader.on('close', function(){
      res(lines);
    });
    // UNCAUGHT ERRORS, USE rej() for others
});
```

Then handling your transform back in your async/await world like this:

```
let data;
let lines = await tokenizer.processFile(req, 'tokenize');
let results = await Promise.map(lines, async (line) => {
  return await Transform(line);
}, { concurrency: 80 });
```

Comment: Thanks Cody, I followed this option.